# Nginx hosted uwsgi django app: only accessible via curl, not by browser

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I'm hosting a Django app using uwsgi and nginx.

If I call `curl -v my_ip:port` it connects. If I direct a browser towards `my_ip:port` it returns a `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` and the connection doesn't show up in the log.

**uWSGI:**

file : `data_collection_project.ini`

```
[uwsgi]
project = data_collection_project
base = /data_nfs/data_collection_project

chdir = %(base)
# /%(project)
home = /home/rootadmin/.virtualenvs/data_collection
#plugins = python

#module = data_collection_project.wsgi:application
module = data_collection_project.wsgi:application
master = true
processes = 2


socket = %(base)/%(project).sock
chmod-socket = 666
```

**nginx:**
file: `/etc/nginx/sites-available`

```
# mysite_nginx.conf

# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
        server unix:///data_nfs/data_collection_project/data_collection_project.sock; # for a file socket
        #server 127.0.0.1:8001; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      8433;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name my_ip; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    # Django media
    location /media  {
        alias /data_nfs/data_collection_project/media;  # your Django project's media files - amend as requir$    }

    location /static {
        alias /data_nfs/data_collection_project/static; # your Django project's static files - amend as requi$    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /data_nfs/data_collection_project/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
}
```

In my understanding, this should make the website available over `my_ip` for outside browsers, but it isn't. I don't understand why. What am I missing?

**EDIT:** If I switch off `uwsgi` and then try to call the `ip:port` there is an errorlog added to `/var/log/nginx/error.log` `connect () to unix:///...sock failed. (111:connection refused)` This error makes sense, since `uwsgi` isn't handling the socket. This seems to mean that `nginx` is working, and does pass the request along to the socket when i do `curl my_ip:port`?

Comment: To many unknowns. Yes the configuration seems to be correct - your service (or at least nginx) should be accessible on the `8433` port. Is nginx listening on the interface you're trying to hit (the one with `my_ip`)? Did you connect with cURL from a remote host through `my_ip`? Is the `my_ip` accessible to the hosts on which you are using the browsers?

Comment: Also what's in `/etc/nginx/sites-available` is by default not evaluated by nginx. Don't you need to at least `ln -s` from sites-available to sites-enabled?

Comment: @McAbra is correct. Nginx won't read confs inside `sites-available`. You need to make a link to the confs (which you want to enable) inside `sites-enabled`. This might help: https://serverfault.com/questions/527630/what-is-the-different-usages-for-sites-available-vs-the-conf-d-directory-for-ngi/527644

Comment: @McAbra There's a Symlink from the .conf in `sites-available` to `sites-enabled`. Would that be what you mean, or is that something else?

Comment: Yes it is. That's fine then. Please reply to the other questions for further advice.

Comment: I can reach it both from the interface(physical ubuntu 12.04 machine that I can only access with SSH) , and from an outside machine on both `url:8443` and `ip:8433`. Yet, not from an browser.

Comment: Updated question with some new information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure but per your EDIT it seems that nginx is passing correctly. Maybe Django's `ALLOWED_HOSTS`? I'd follow these steps:

1. Make sure that `data_collection_project.ini` is the one ini used (maybe try command line arguments instead of an ini file as a one of test).
2. Add `deamonize` to your `data_collection_project.ini` to make uwsgi log to a file.
3. Check if it's not Django that is dropping your connection.

Comment: The insight that maybe it wasn't nginx that was wrong helped me out in the end. It turned out that somebody had closed the port on the bastion-server in between. The one that I had been using for the last few months. When i figured that out, it was as easy as just opening that port again.